# Create timestampdiif function in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm trying to create function in redshift that will calculate the exactly gap between two dates, like timestampdiff in MySQL.

I'm running the attached script

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.timestampdiff (a text,b timestamp, c timestamp )
   RETURNS INT
AS $$
BEGIN
    case when a=second then datediff(second,b,c)
         when a=minute then datediff(second,b,c)/60
         when a=hour then datediff(second,b,c)/(60*60)
         when a=day then datediff(second,b,c)/(60*60*24)
         when a=week then datediff(second,b,c)/(60*60*24*7)
         when a=month then datediff(second,b,c)/(60*60*24*7*52) end;
END;
$$
   LANGUAGE SQL
   VOLATILE
```

but i received the following error:

ERROR: Create Function is not supported for language sql.

Comment: First: when using `language SQL` you can't have `begin .. end` blocks. Those are for PL/pgSQL. Second: you need some kind of `SELECT` for a `SQL` function, you can't just write `case...`  I don't know Redshift, but in Postgres there is no function `datediff` you would use `b - c` which returns an `interval`. If you want that e.g. in seconds you can use `extract(epoch from (b-c))`

Comment: hi , thanks but can you right an example , redshift have datediff function , its the same syntax as MySQL

Comment: Amazon Redshift is (mostly) compatible with PostgreSQL. In PostgreSQL, you can subtract two timestamps to obtain an `interval`, which can be used in various ways.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody's search lands here, Amazon Redshift has the [DATEDIFF](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEDIFF_function.html) fuction.

```
DATEDIFF ( datepart, {date|timestamp}, {date|timestamp} )
```

[datepart](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Dateparts_for_datetime_functions.html) specifies the part of of the date or timestamp that you want the function to operate on.  For example,

```
select datediff(hours, '01-01-2019 8:30:00','01-01-2019 10:00:00');

date_diff
---------
2
```